# How I can get dict "Current" via Python and pytest

Tags: python-3.x

Now I wrote this code

```
r = requests.get(BET.format())
 a = json.loads(r.text)
print(a)
```

where I received all json response. And than need to get "current" to parse value from that, using python and pytest:

```
{
    "command": "bet",
    "status": "ok",
    "game": {
        "current": {
            "lines": 25,
            "bet": 10,
            "state": "idle",
            "transitions": [
                "bet"
            ]
        },
        "symbols": {
            "symbols": [
                [
                    2,
                    2,
                    5
                ],
                [
                    2,
                    2,
                    10
                ],
                [
                    9,
                    9,
                    9
                ],
                [
                    6,
                    2,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    6,
                    5,
                    8
                ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use dict.get() with multidimensional dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003408/how-to-use-dict-get-with-multidimensional-dict)

Comment: Do you know how to work with dictionaries generally? Have you tried working with this one, and what happened? Also, note that requests has a method to parse the body as JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value associated with the `"current"` key in the dict literal above using `a['game']['current']`.